# SQL difficult calculation

Tags: sql

Asume we have a table with columns A,B,C, where A has data type of a String, B and C are both Integers. I need to make another table from this one with 4 columns - A, B, sum(C) and D, where D is the sum of values in C with the same value in column A (as this one) and value in B less by 1 (than this one). For example, for given values "a" at A and 1 at B it should return (in column D) the sum of all of the values in C where value at A is "a" and value at B is zero.

Comment: "SQL difficult calculation" doesn't look like a good title for this question.

Comment: What is your query so far?  And are you asking for help with the INSERT statement (or also with creating the table)?

Comment: It will be better to visualise if you provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What is the table definition? Can you post some sample data? What would the results be of that sample data? What code have you tried to far and what problems are you having with it?

Comment: Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
    And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 
 this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something similar to this query:

```
declare @t table (a varchar(1), b int, c int)
insert @t values
('a', 1, 1),
('a', 2, 2),
('b', 3, 3),
('a', 4, 4)


select t.a, t.b,
    (
        select sum(t1.c)
        from @t t1
    ) c,
    (
        select isnull(sum(t2.c), 0)
        from @t t2
        where t2.a = t.a and t2.b = t.b - 1
    )
from @t t
```